# Snowflake: Unsupported feature 'MATERIALIZED VIEWS'

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create materialized view in Snowflake and i get the unsupported feature error.

**Error: 000002 (0A000): Unsupported feature 'MATERIALIZED VIEWS'.**

I have a table called cell_towers2. When I try to create a new materialized view with the following DDL (in the web console)

```
create materialized view v1 as
    select * from cell_towers2 WHERE net = 2
```

Comment: [MATERIALIZED VIEWS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-materialized-view.html) `Materialized views require Enterprise Edition.`

Answer (score 0):

Run the current_version to check the version of your Snowflake account:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/current_version.html

```
SELECT CURRENT_VERSION();
```

If it's not Enterprise Edition, contact Snowflake support to upgrade the edition (if you want to use MVs)